# DNN Database Repository Reuse in Console Application

Tags: c#, repository, dotnetnuke

I have a project based on the Chris Hammond, Christoc, module template.  I have a ton of code that I use to access data an external database.  In my repositories I change the database from the default to whichever I need for that particular object.  I do so with code that looks like this:

```
using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance(MyModuleSettingsBase.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY))
{
    var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Product>();
    products = rep.Get().ToList();
}
```

The default database is switched in the call to `.Instance().`  The repositories are used by my custom DNN modules.  The repository is part of the solution that contains multiple custom modules.  When I compile and install using the Extensions part of DNN, everything works well.  In the code above, `MyModuleSettingsBase.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY` is found in a file MyModuleSettingsBase.cs file of my module solution.  It is set to a simple string like "ProductDatabase".  In the solution for the base DNN install (not the module solution), within the web.config file, there is a value in `<connectionStrings>` with `name="ProductDatabase"` which contains the actual connection string.  This all links up fine on the DNN website.

Now I am writing a console application that does some monitoring of the site.  I want to access the database to check values in the product table.  I would like to reuse all of the repository code I have written.  In an attempt to do so, I added a reference to the MyModules.dll file so I would only have one copy of the base code.  This works to give me access to all the objects and the associated repositories  but when I attempt to query data it fails.  When debugging I can see that it fails on the line:

```
using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance(MyModuleSettingsBase.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY))
```

When viewed in a debugger, the string value `MyModuleSettingsBase.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY` is correctly set to "ProductDatabase" but the code is unable to link this with the actual connection string.  I don't know where it would be checking for the connections string when running from my console application.  I attempted to put a `<connectionStrings>` section into my App.config file but this didn't do the trick.

Is it possible to have `MyModuleSettingsBase.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY` map to the connection string in an external application which references the DLL?

If so, where can I set the value of my connection string so it matches up to the key value stored in `MyModuleSettingsBase.DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING_KEY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was faced similar problem 3 months ago, at that time I want to use DNN core libraries in my console application but I was failed.

I placed my queries in DNN official forum website and I got a valid response from Wes Tatters (DNN MVP).

Here is the post link: [Reference URL](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/118/postid/512293/scope/posts)

As your requirement of monitoring, I suggest you to create [DNN Schedule Application](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2011/01/18/creating-dotnetnuke-scheduled-jobs.aspx). You can schedule it within DNN (Host->AdvancedSettings->Schedule), even good point is that you can use your repositories (DNN Libraries) in that schedule application.

I hope it solved your problem. Let me know if you have any questions.